# Realistic combat AI

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons, artificial-intelligence, drone

The idea of combat robots is simple, they are robotic soldiers that don't eat, don't sleep and don't rest, but they never touch the issue of the AI they employ. The AI of a combat robot must meet the following requirements.

1. Be able to differentiate friend from foe without the use of special markers such as QR tags, radio frequency transmitters for tagging, or any mechanism that is easy to counterfeit. If I know of the existence of radio frequency identifiers that are used mainly in aircraft and that special forces often have infrared tags for night vision operations, both options are valid answers as long as they are a support and not the basis of the arrest. What I mean is that putting a brightly colored uniform or a continuously active radio transmitter are not valid solutions, due to the loss of stealth and to base the detention only on these elements either because of the ease of counterfeiting.
2. It must be able to differentiate combatants from civilians, it must be able to detect if a civilian is a camouflaged attacker. False positives are more tolerable than false negatives, but it is necessary to minimize incidents of civilian fire as much as possible.
3. Must be able to detect automatically identify enemies automatically.
4. Must be able to acquire priority targets, seek cover, and coordinate tactically locally.
   As architecture I thought of: An input stage consisting of convolutional neural networks that are responsible for detecting objects from a 3D image produced in real time by a NeRF system and a depth map generated by a combination of stereo vision and a model similar to this. https://google.github.io/mannequinchallenge/www/index.html
   [image]
   [image]
   The output of this is fed to a transformer which is responsible for using the data from the convolutional networks and deciding what is enemy, what is ally and what is civilian, in addition the previous frames are retained and used to provide memory to the system. Once the transformer has decided who is who and marks them, a second transformer decides how to use the terrain and fight (similar to this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.07528.pdf).

The question is how should the AI be trained to learn to differentiate allies from enemies? What should they pay attention to in order to make that differentiation?
I am writing a novel in which an army of automatons is a centerpiece of the plot and I would like to be as specific and realistic as possible. And the automatons are terrestrial/amphibious not aerial drones.

Comment: Were I to have a definitive answer to all those questions (God, aren't they quite many of them?), I'd probably be employed in a huge multinational defense industry with a seven-digit salary (as the head of research) and, even if I'd be bored over my head and decide to take a break on WB.SE, the contractual terms will prohibit me from disclosing anything about. **Do you really think you are going to obtain a realistic answer here?**

Comment: " Be able to differentiate friend from foe without the use of special markers " - this is not always the humans can, ha ha. 
All your requirements mean only one thing - AI must be real artificial INTELLIGENCE, the "outsoul", that is, be truly intelligent (and this is not a guarantee). :>

Comment: Can you [edit] this to bring it into compliance with our 1 question per post policy.

Comment: There, I've narrowed it down to the question of how to learn to detect.

Comment: "Should" is a very subjective term that is often decided by weighing an uncountable number of subjective factors. Do you mean to ask about how *could* an AI be trained instead? You're still asking two questions. How to train an AI to do a task, and What will the AI pay attention to to differentiate between friend and foe.

Comment: In this context what you should pay attention to is part of the training so form a single question. Or at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: This question is basically asking "how can I make an AI that does what I need it to". The answer is "you do it the exact same way everyone else does". As such, this question is not a proper fit for this site and should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is how should the AI be trained to learn to differentiate allies from enemies? What should they pay attention to in order to make that differentiation?

The way machine learning works in the current world: you don't bother with this question. You let a computer figure out what criteria are and are not important for a classification task.

The way AI training would work with current technology is to:

1. take a randomly configured neural network
2. feed it with the sensor-data of couple thousand real-life situations where you know how the AI is supposed to act
3. Take a note of how many of these situations get categorized correctly (even if just by chance)
4. Make some random change to the neural network
5. See if it now performs better or worse
6. If it performs better, keep using that new network and make a change to it. Otherwise, return to the old one and try a different change.
7. Repeat for a couple million times

The end result is a neural network which can differ between enemies and friendlies with a relatively high accuracy, even though you have no idea how exactly it does it.

For further watching, here is an entertaining and educational video about machine learning: [CGP Grey: How machines learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9OHn5ZF4Uo).

This can sometimes give you interesting flaws, though, especially when your test data is biased. For example, Amazon once tried to create an AI to replace their hiring managers. They did that by training it with the decisions their human hiring managers made. The result was that the AI [did its best to copy the sexist bias of human hiring managers](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-45809919). So when you train your combat AI with the decisions your human soldiers made in the field, then it will also try to replicate any *wrong* decisions they made. But even if you filter for that by making sure you test for the *right* course of action in all test-cases, the variety of data might be a problem. When you train your AI only with data collected by the US Army during the Afghanistan war, then it might be trained to assume that Middle-Eastern people are a higher danger than any other ethnicity. This might even work as long as you use the AI in the middle-east. But it will then fail spectacularly when you deploy it to an entirely different theater and confront it with enemies of a different ethnicity. For example, if deployed in Sub-Saharan Africa, it might refuse to shoot anyone, because all the people with black skin in its training data were US soldiers.

Answer (score 7):

*"How should the artificial intelligence be trained to learn to differentiate allies from enemies?"*

It will be trained in the same way that natural intelligences are trained.

- People wearing the same uniform as you are likely friendly.
- People wearing the ugly uniform of the enemy are surely enemies.
- People shooting at you are clearly unfriendly.
- Soldiers, natural or artificial, get training in recognizing the profiles of vehicles used by their own army (don't shoot at them) and the profiles of the vehicles used by the enemy (destroy them).
- In the context of fighting against a guerrila, soldiers get training in recognizing behavioral clues which may indicate that a civilian is an enemy combatant.

And so on.

Of course, this means that such an artificial intelligence is not something which will be available any time soon... At the present moment, the best we can do is program the robot to kill anything that moves and does not carry the super secret friendly identification QR code, or does not provide the correct answer when challenged by the [IFF system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe).

Comment: Modern object detection systems are quite robust. With enough computing power and a good simulator, you should be able to train in a few months.

Comment: Ummm... right. Damn'd the false positives, we're the good guys... Our fire, by definition, is always friendly fire.

Comment: Let's just ignore the fact that most current AI target recognition has some serious problems - such as tanks being more likely to be treated as Russian if they are in snow, because more of the pictures fed into the AI of Russian tanks show them in snow.

Answer (score 6):

Your thinking of a combat AI as a resident consciousness within a single robot, dependent on the continued functionality of that robot for its existence.  Imagine instead a combat AI distributed across a thousand robotic bodies, linked together on multiple channel radio, laser and direct wired connection.

Want to know who the enemy is?  Send a lightweight fast-moving robot body out into the middle of the battle field and see who shoots at it, then return the favor by shooting back from a thousand different vantage points.   Send guardian bodies out to protect the ones that don't shoot at you, but keep track of who shoots at them.  Everyone is suspect, including those being guarded.  Any offensive action on the part of any human leads to an immediate communal response...  a fatal response.

Once you are the dominant presence on the battle field, order all humans to drop their weapons.  Kill any who don't immediately comply.  Strip search the survivors for hidden weapons and kamikaze explosives, then escort them off the battlefield.

The secret to being an effective combat AI lies in investing your multiple bodies to answer the questions that single-bodied humans can afford to ask?  The only way to truly know if another person wants you dead is to give them a chance to kill you.  As long as you have bodies to spare, you can afford to ask what the humans cannot.

Comment: That's a good idea, but multiple robots working with a single central AI has the problem that if communication is blocked the robots stops, plus it adds the risk of being hacked. I think the best way to implement something like that is to let the units radio each other and transfer the information they need, although having one peek out and just shoot back is an interesting strategy. But as you put it, integration with human soldiers would be impossible.

Comment: Depending on the tech level at your disposal, there are un-block-able communication methods available.  Quantum entanglement for example.

Comment: This works even if the 'bots are independent. Each one processes and evaluates its surroundings, and passes on important information to a general broadcast. Getting shot at is important information. And the loss of lightweight recon drones is... expected.

Answer (score 3):

The same way many real world convolutional neural networks are trained: a huge collection of data that has been labeled by humans. Ever used an image captcha? You've helped train a model. Have your soldiers wear cameras on patrol. Send the footage to your data labeling team. Each video clip would have different types of objects coded (friendly soldier, enemy soldier, deer, etc.), along with a kill/no-kill label. You'd then put unarmed robots in the field and have them make lethal force decisions. In the real world, I think that's where this type of technology should stop, but for the purposes of your story you'd have a team of QA staff review all the robot's decisions to make sure they were correct. If there are problems, generate more data using the situations where the wrong decisions were made. Repeat until it passes all tests, which is the earliest point where your robots could be given guns. Keep evaluating the robot's performance to make sure the AI hasn't started making mistakes. (I'm a data scientist IRL and that last part is easy to overlook.)

"What should they pay attention to in order to make that differentiation?"
Let the AI worry about this. If you want to use convolutional neural networks, you should focus on creating as much data as possible and testing in combat conditions. The network will figure out the important parts on its own. If you want to learn more about how this kind of network works, check out the videos at fast.ai.

Comment: I think in this case reinforcement learning and imitation learning for decision making would be faster. As for training convolutional networks with giant datasets created by soldiers is a great idea.

Comment: Worked brilliantly for [Microsoft](https://www.theverge.com/2016/3/24/11297050/tay-microsoft-chatbot-racist)

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1425/)